# How to collect values from one map after removing some entires against each key and produce another map using streams (Java 8)

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a map. In map correspond to each key there is a List of 50 objects. Basically I made that map using Streams. What I did, I used `groupingBy` function of stream. Here are the steps that I took.

```
Map<Long, List<Learner>> learnersMap = learnersDataList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Learner::getLearnerEnrollmentId));
```

Then I seperated those records that has less than 50 count or equal to 50 count against each key using the code below

```
Map<Long, List<Learner>> answersLessThan50CountLearnersMap = 
             learnersMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getValue().stream().count() < 50)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

and

```
Map<Long, List<Learner>> validLearnersMap = 
            learnersMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getValue().stream().count() == 50)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

Now I want that from `answersLessThan50CountLearnersMap`, I produce a map that contain only one record from List. I mean suppose if Map looks like this

```
1-->[Learner, Learner, Learner, ....]
2-->[Learner, Learner, Learner, ....]
3-->[Learner, Learner, Learner, ....]
```

Then I want to produce a map like this

```
1--> Learner
2--> Learner
3--> Learner
```

Actually all the records in the List are redundant. Like first name in all the 50 learners object against key 1 is same. Only one record is distinct but I don't need that because I have to send email by getting learner records from Learner Object and don't need that distinct record. Same for key `2` and `3`. Like I can say that

```
entrySet.getValue.stream.findFirst() or entrySet.getValue.stream.limit(1)
```

for each entry in entrySet.In other words I want to produce map like `Map<Long, Learner>` from `answersLessThan50CountLearnersMap`

Can I do it by applying streams operations to it. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, consider that not everything is better just because you are using `Stream`s.

The first thing which jumped into my eye is `p.getValue().stream().count()` whereas `p.getValue()` actually returns a `List`. So `p.getValue().size()` is obviously more reasonable here.

Further, if you want only the first element of a `List`, calling `list.get(0)` is a proven way, simpler than `list.stream().findFirst()`. If the size of the list might be zero, you have to check that but in one of your cases, it’s already proven to be non-zero (as the `size` is equal to `50` mandated by the `Predicate`).

And you can do it right where you define what values your `Map` shall contain:

```
Map<Long, Learner> answersLessThan50CountLearnersMap = 
     learnersMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getValue().size() < 50)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(),
                              p -> p.getValue().isEmpty()? null: p.getValue().get(0)));
Map<Long, Learner> validLearnersMap = 
    learnersMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getValue().size() == 50)// implies non-empty list
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue().get(0)));
```

---

If you want give up compactness for efficiency, you may consider that you are only interested in the first element of each, right when you create your first map, in other words, all you need is the first element and the count rather than an entirely filled `List`. So we need an alternative container, holding only the first element and the count, suitable for collecting the data:

```
class LearnerAndCount {
    Learner first;
    int count;
    LearnerAndCount add(Learner l) {
        if(first==null) first=l;
        count++;
        return this;
    }
    LearnerAndCount merge(LearnerAndCount lac) {
        if(first==null) first=lac.first;
        count+=lac.count;
        return this;
    }
}
```

collect the information

```
Map<Long, LearnerAndCount> learnersMap = learnersDataList.stream().collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(Learner::getLearnerEnrollmentId,
    Collector.of(LearnerAndCount::new, LearnerAndCount::add, LearnerAndCount::merge)));
```

and use it for creating the two maps

```
Map<Long, Learner> answersLessThan50CountLearnersMap = 
     learnersMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getValue().count < 50)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, p -> p.getValue().first));
Map<Long, Learner> validLearnersMap = 
     learnersMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getValue().count == 50)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, p -> p.getValue().first));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestions. I will certainly act upon your suggestions in future work. As far as `answersLessThan50CountLearnersMap ` is concerned you are right that I should get `Map<Long, Learner>` in one attempt as you did. But for `validLearnersMap ` I can't do that because first I have to process all 50 records against each key in `validLearnersMap `, I need to apply some business logic to make data from 50 records, that's why I only asked for `answersLessThan50CountLearnersMap`. Anyways thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

But I don't know how good is it as I am new to streams. Here what I did.

```
Map<Long, Learner> invalidLearnersMap = 
            answersLessThan50CountLearnersMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p ->  {
                Optional<Learner> learner = p.getValue().stream().findFirst();
                if (learner.isPresent()) {
                    Learner learner = learner.get();
                    return learner;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }

            }));
```

I can do that also where I was getting `lessThan50CountMap`. Anyways Thanks.